# Eclipse can't find the JRE

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I'm having a problem with the JRE on Ubuntu 14.04.

**EDIT:**
the computer has no connection to Internet, so I'm using the apt-offline method (I did that already with the installation of eclipse).

Im trying to run eclipse cdt, when I play it, I get this message:

> A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be
>   available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found
>   after searching the following locations: /usr/lib/eclipse/jre/bin/java
>   java in your current PATH

the `java --version` command gave me that output:

```
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

So I understand that the JRE not installed yet, so I installed it:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless
```

and that is the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openjdk-7-jre-headless is already the newest version.
openjdk-7-jre-headless set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
```

after `java --version` command, the output is again like the previous output.

I tried to read [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/191427/how-to-find-out-if-java-is-installed-in-ubuntu-and-how-to-install-it/) and [that](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get) and some more articles

**EDIT 2:**
I also tried to add the path `usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64` to the `etc/profile` file:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jre1.8.0_60
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

I don't understand what I am missing or doing wrong. Or maybe the JRE is installed but Eclipse doesn't know it somehow?

I will be very happy for some guidance.

Answer (score 3):

Install via

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

You might also add the JDK manually to Eclipse:

```
Windows -> Preferences
=> Java / Installed JREs
```

If it is not listed, click "Add", choose "Standard VM", and click "Next". Set "JRE Home" as something like `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64` (navigate via "Directroy" button).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment, see the edit. I also tried to add the path usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 to the .ini file of eclipse

Comment: After installing via `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk` does command `java` work on command line?

Comment: You might also need to set $JAVA_HOME

Comment: What do you mean by "adding to the .ini" file?

Comment: the command `java` still didn't work.. and by "adding to the .ini file", see the EDIT 2.  thank you.

Comment: I am not familiar with ini file. Is the jdk listed in Eclipse (as described in my answer)

Comment: Btw: there is a mixup of Java 7 and Java 8 paths in your question... Is it correct in you system?

Answer (score -1):

try to add the java path in the  ~/.bashrc.

Answer (score -1):

Just copy the "jre" folder from jdk and paset it inside "eclipse" folder